# SIP Phones unreliable past 12.04 - Empathy additional features?

Tags: 12.04, empathy, voip, sip

I am currently running Empathy SIP, which works "ok" but it's definitely not up to the same standard that QuteCom is on Windows. QuteCom on Ubuntu is unstable, but yet still in the stable repository. I've tried others with absolutely no stable results.

Can anyone provide a stable softphone with business grade features (i.e. transfer, conference) or point me in the right direction to ask for the features in a future build of Empathy?

Or even better, a fix for this sip audio nightmare?

Answer (score 1):

Twinkle does a pretty good job, and it has the features that you mention:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/twinkle